# What is an "item" in Rust?

Tags: rust, definition

The [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org) makes several references to the word "item", which confers the word a technical meaning in the context of the Rust programming language. For example, see [Chapter 07-03](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html):

> The way privacy works in Rust is that all items (functions, methods, structs, enums, modules, and constants) are private by default. Items in a parent module can’t use the private items inside child modules, but items in child modules can use the items in their ancestor modules.

What is an item and is there a comprehensive list of all the kinds that there are in Rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Items - Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html):

> An *item* is a component of a [crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/crates-and-source-files.html). [...] There are several kinds of items:
>
> - Modules
> - `extern crate` declarations
> - `use` declarations
> - Function definitions
> - Type definitions
> - Struct definitions
> - Enumeration definitions
> - Union definitions
> - Constant items
> - Static items
> - Trait definitions
> - Implementations
> - `extern` blocks

Answer (score 1):

> An item is simply any declaration that could appear globally in a program or module, such as a ***fn***, ***struct***, or ***use***.

Reference: Programming Rust: Fast, Safe Systems Development (2nd Edition)